# Installing MySQL-python with easy-install failed

Tags: python, linux, centos, mysql-python, centos6.5

I'm struggling with installing MySQL-python on my Centos VPS. I have "main" Python 2.6 (one that came automatically with CentOS) and another one I installed after (2.7). So I used this command:

```
easy_install-2.7 MySQL-python
```

But it reproduces following error:

```
Searching for MySQL-python
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQL-python/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQL-python/: unknown url type: https -- Some        packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'MySQL-python' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: unknown url type: https -- Some packages may     not be found!
No local packages or download links found for MySQL-python
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('MySQL-python')
```

Thanks for reading my question and possibly trying to help!

Comment: Why don't you use `pip` instead `easy_install`?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi I tried, but pip downloads everything for my 2.6 python, as I tried, pip-2.7 is not working like that. How do I use pip-2.7?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're using an old version of `easy_install`, that may be the root of problem. You can follow instructions from `distribute` [doc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/0.7.3) package, and than install `pip`. Since you have installed `pip` you can install `MySQL-python`easily.

Comment: I did that, but when I try to install it using pip, it installs it for python 2.6, not 2.7, which I want to...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try use some sentence,which include mysqldb.